# Store Numbers as Binary in files

Tags: java, file, ascii, store

I have numbers written as ASCII codes in my file. For example "9" is stored as two bytes 57 i.e. 8 bits in total.

I want to optimize storage by just storing those numbers as binary values for example numbers from 0-9 to be stored using 4 bits only.

Any help?!

Comment: Do you mean "9" is stored as "57"? I cannot see how can an ascii 57 uses 2 bytes.

Comment: yes char "9" is stored in the file as two bytes one is 5 and the other is 7

Comment: You are likely to make bugs with your algorithm here. Can you not use Zip library to compress your file? Zip or an archive library has much more sophisticated algorithm than what you can come up yourself.

Comment: BTW: '9' takes up one byte, two with a separator. If you store it as an `int` binary it takes 4 bytes, that's twice as large.  Using binary is no guarantee it will be much smaller.  If you want more compact I suggest using GZIPOutputStream to compress the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write them binary like that

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Bin {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream("\\test.bin");
        String digits="12345";
        char[] chars = digits.toCharArray();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < chars.length ; i+= 2 ) {
            byte b1 = (byte) (chars[i] - (byte) '0');
            byte b2 = (byte) (i < chars.length-1 ? chars[i+1] - (byte) '0' : 0xf);
            fos.write((byte) ((b1 << 4) | b2 ));
        }
        fos.close();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("\\test.bin");
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] buf = new byte[100];
        int read = fis.read(buf);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < read ; i++ ) {
            byte both = (byte) bais.read();
            byte b1 = (byte) ((both >> 4 ) & 0xf);
            byte b2 = (byte) (both  & 0xf) ;
            result.append( Character.forDigit(b1, 10));
            if ( b2 != 0xf ) {
                result.append(Character.forDigit(b2,10));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

But I doubt that this will be very useful

Comment: Great! Man Just tell me then how can I read my characters back and store them in a string. The string we started with

Comment: @shaklasah Reading them back was way harder than I thought, note the 0xf written in case the source string is odd. It is used as padding since we can only write complete bytes.

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?
0 => 0000
1 => 0001
2 => 0010
3 => 0011
4 => 0100
5 => 0101
6 => 0110
7 => 0111
8 => 1000
9 => 1001

Comment: Yes but how am I going to write this to the file?!

Comment: you can use file output stream to write into a file

Comment: yes but that will treat each digit as two bytes again and it will become even worse as 0000 will be considered as 8 byte :S

Comment: In this case you should write your own conversion mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with the standard [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) which can write primitive types to the output in a *portable way*.

It has [`writeLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeLong%28long%29), [`writeInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29). With these methods you can write out your data, then later load it with [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)'s [`readLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLong%28%29) and [`readInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29).

If this is not compact enough you can compress it later with any compression library.

Answer (score 0):

If you write character it will take 1byte for each character. You have to write binary or boolean data. You can represent 5=>0101 but if you write 0101 as a character it will take 4bytes and if you write binary or boolean it will take bits.